# Why is the reverse image $\Phi^{-1}$ Lebesgue-measurable?

Tags: lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

Let $E \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ be a lebesgue-measurable set and let $f,g : E \to \mathbb{R}$  be lebesgue-mesurable functions.

Define $\Phi: E \to \mathbb{R^2}$ by
$$
\Phi (x)=
\begin{pmatrix}
f(x) \\
g(x) \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then, prove that $\Phi^{-1}(U)$ is lebesgue-measurable set for open set $U \in \mathbb{R^2}$.

Let $U\in \mathbb{R^2}$ be open and I have to prove
$$
\Phi^{-1}(U)=\left\{ x \in E \ \Bigg| \ \Phi (x)=
\begin{pmatrix}
f(x) \\
g(x) \\
\end{pmatrix}
\in U
\right\}
$$
is open, but I cannot know what I should do and I'm stacked.

I would like you to give me some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$U$ is a countable union of sets of the form $A\times B$ where $A$ and $B$ are open in $\mathbb R$. Hence the inverse image is a countable union of sets of the form $f^{-1}(A)\cap g^{-1}(B)$.

[Given any point $(x,y) \in U$ there is an open rectangle $(a,b)\times (c,d)$ containing $(x,y)$, contained in $U$ such that $a,b,c,d $ are all rational numbers. This gives you a countable family of open sets of the form $A \times B$ ($A,B$ open) whose union is $U$].

Comment: @Kavi_Rama_Murthy Why can we say that open set $U \in \mathbb{R^2}$ is a countable union of sets of the form $A \times B$ where $A$ and $B$ are open in $\mathbb{R}$? Is there a theorem or proposition about it ?

Comment: @EPA I have added a proof of this statement.